# Replace symbols with letter in microsoft office word file Python

Tags: python

I have text file with 
text e.g `izvo|enje ovla{}ujem Milivojevi} garae ~lan`.

Usually i use in `Microsoft office word` `Find` and `Replace` option for each symbol to change letter.

I want to get text `izvodenje ovlascujem Milivojevic garaze clan`

So

- symbol `|` change to `c`
- symbol `{` change to `s`
- symbol `~` change to `c` 
  , et cetera.

How can I do it? I want to automate this process, save this code in file and use this code like script.
I would like to use `Python`, (im really beginner)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time reading on how to provide a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: people here don't do your homework for you. you need to come up with at least some that is doing something, and ask people to help you complete it. not to ask them write your programs for you.

Answer (score 1):

Store the string in a var and use replace('old str', 'new str') function

```
string = "izvo|enje ovla{}ujem Milivojevi} gara`e ~lan"
print string.replace("|","d").replace("{", "s").replace("}", "c").replace("`", "z").replace("~", "c")
```

Comment: Can u write code here ? Give me one example of code. I want to use this .exe file and use this code like script.

Comment: This is not an .exe it's .py file.

Comment: Thank you on suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    sentence = f.read()
correct = sentence.replace('|', 'c')
print(correct)
```

prints:

```
izvocenje ovla{}ujem Milivojevi} gara`e ~lan
```

the rest is trivial, so it´s a good Chance to learn python for yourself

Answer (score 1):

The more simple way to do that is using method replace like below:

```
text= "one two three"
text = text.replace("two", "2")
```

For multiple replaces I suggest a loop like this:

```
text= "one two three"
replaceable = {'one': '1', 'two': '2', 'three': '3'}
for string, new_string in replaceable.items(): 
    text = text.replace(string, new_string)
```